# how to create a custom tiled image?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, quartz-2d

I have a small-sized image and I want to obtain an image which has various numbers of this small-sized image. I've started by creating an `uiimageview` for each image but it didn't go well.

So is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't go well for each image? All the images are same as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your image is named `pattern.png` and you want to add the tiled as background to a UIView:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pattern.png"];
  self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:patternImage];
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need to repeat my pattern image with user-input values such as 3x5 2x4 etc.